# Insert values into an already created column via a select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert values into an already created column via a select query like

```
     UPDATE 
          [X].[dbo].[Table]
     SET
          [Year] = (Select substring (COLUMN_1,467,2) from [X].[dbo].[Table])
```

Is there any way to do this without creating a new column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would just do:

```
UPDATE [X].[dbo].[Table]
    SET [Year] = substring(COLUMN_1, 467, 2);
```

A subquery is not necessary and not desirable.

Alternatively, you can add a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE [X].[dbo].[Table] ADD [Year] AS (substring(COLUMN_1, 467, 2));
```

With a computed column, the value is calculated when needed -- hence it is always up-to-date.

Comment: Thanks, @Gordon Linoff.